# Toad data modeler scripting: Entity.Attributes[i].Domain returns undefined

Tags: toad, toad-scripting

I'm trying to programmatically retrieve the domain of a table's field.

We only use domains in our model, as shown below:

[image]

The code is the following:

```
for (var counterAttr = 0; counterAttr < TableObject.Attributes.Count; counterAttr++)
{ 
   var attr = TableObject.Attributes.GetObject(counterAttr);

   Log.Information("Field[" +counterAttr +"]: " + attr.Name + " (" + attr.Domain + ")");  
}
```

But unfortunately it outputs as follows:

```
Field[0]: LDAP_USED_GROUP_ID (undefined)
Field[1]: LDAP_DOMAIN_ID (undefined)
Field[2]: LDAP_USED_GROUP_NAME (undefined)
...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, found through Toad forums, is to use:

```
attr.Domain.Name
```

even if `attr.Domain` itself is `undefinded`... who knows?